# How to tell when all MongoDB change stream events have arrived?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

I have a requirement that, after some writes to MongoDB, I want my application to wait until all the corresponding change events have been processed by my change stream listener.

Right now, I write a recognizable value into a particular `echo` field that is otherwise unused. When my change stream listener sees that value arrive, I know it has also seen all prior writes, because the change stream is totally ordered. This works even if I run my application as a replica set: all writes from any replica that "happen before" the echo will arrive in the change stream before the `echo` write.

Is there a way to achieve this without performing a write?

Specifically: I'd like to wait until all writes acknowledged before a certain point in time have had their change stream events processed by a particular cursor; and I'd prefer to be able to do this without granting my app write permission to that MongoDB server.

Answer (score 1):

The write to the `echo` field seems like the best solution. Changestreams only provides document change events, not meta events like "all the changes are complete" event you're looking for.

### Other Solution 1

Another solution is simply to have a timer if your document updates are time-sensitive. After processing a change stream event, refresh a timer. If the timer expires, you can trigger the next step.

### Other Solution 2

Another solution is to track which documents have changed and save them somewhere. Your changestream listener can track the incoming changes against your tracking. In node.js, this would look like:

```
> sender.js
saveRecordedChanges(changes.map(getChangeId))

> changeStreamListener.js
changes = getRecordedChanges();
changeStream.on('change', function (change) {
    ...process change...

    changes = changes.filter(c => getChangeId(c) === getChangeId(change))
    if (isEmpty(changes)){
         ...run some code...
    }
}
```